# java singleton class 

Tags: java, singleton

I have a singleton parent class extended by a child class which is not singleton. If i instantiate my child class more than once, will there be more than one object of parent class. Please clarify.

I mean, basically, i want to know if a child class is instantiated, will a new instance of the parent class will also be created. Please explain.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. If you are implementing the singleton pattern for some instance, this instance is of particular type: either the parent class or the child. In both cases it is singleton. If you instantiate the child in some other context it is no longer singleton.

Comment: Dpends on the constructors in your child class... if there are some public "normal" constructors, then it will be instantiated more than once...

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov,Hi, I am not subclassing a singleton. I just wanted to understand the behavior like what will happend if a singleton is subclassed.

Comment: @ihavprobs, A Singleton means there can only be one, if you have more than one, its no longer a Singleton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you instantiate a class you don't instantiate any of its parents. So technically where will be no instances of the singleton class.

However, if your 'singleton' class can be inherited (i.e. it's not final), then it is not really a singleton.

For example all the members of it will be also in the child, so there will potentially be more than one instance of them - so it's not really a singleton.